# Listen certain redux action in components

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Is there any way to listen certain action in component using `redux-thunk` middleware ? or do i really need to use `redux-saga` or `redux-observable` something to achieve this?

Here is my redux-thunk async action , i just simply want to close the dialog after `TICKET_CREATE_SUCCESS` action dispatched

```
export const createTicketEffects = (ticket: Ticket): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> => {
    return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => {
        dispatch(TicketActions.createTicket(ticket));
        return await TicketService.create(ticket)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                dispatch(TicketActions.createTicketSuccess(data.data, data.message));
            })
            .catch((error) => dispatch(TicketActions.createTicketError(error)));
    };
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not in the sense you're asking, no.  Components can't "listen for dispatched actions".

However, thunks can return a promise, and you *can* wait for that promise to be returned from `dispatch(someThunk())`:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#thunks-and-promises

Also, note that you can simplify that thunk using Redux Toolkit's `createAsyncThunk` API:

```
const createTicketEffects = createAsyncThunk(
  'tickets/createTickets',
  async (ticket: Ticket) => {
    const response = await TicketService.create(ticket);
    return res.data; // example: not sure what you're doing with `res.message`
  }
)
```